# How can I query Json from the client side, kind of like a query or SQL-type language?

Tags: jquery

What's the best way to query JSON from the client side? i.e. I have 100 json items, i query and it returns the 4 json items that match?

Maybe a plugin or pattern that would help?

Comment: could be a LINQ type, but doesn't even need to be that advanced.  Just need to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for a Linq equivalent for JavaScript, try this library:

http://jslinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: nice... i have a feeling ill be using this in the near future.

Comment: I ended up just doing a loop and using .push to build my filter json object for use.  The LINQ to js could be a good solution in general and answers my question.